# Dividing large file into chunks and process each chunk in separate thread, speed up?

Tags: android, multithreading, file-io, parallel-processing, chunked-encoding

In my test Android application, I need to process a large file such as compression, encryption, erasure encoding, and etc...
In order to speed-up the process, I spawn multiple threads, each thread read and process different part of a file, and finally merge/append the result together. (Using Java NIO)

I already tried it and there is really some speed-up, 50% or more depending on which storage technique was involved.
There are many similar SO question on this BUT they mainly discussed how it will not improve the I/O speed due to the limitation on single spinning hard disk.
But in my case, it is on multi-cores Android device, which uses flash memory.
Therefore I am not really sure if the speed-up is due to parallel processing or due to caching in RAM.

and my main question is:
Am I doing the right thing? (since I am on multi-cores Android device)
or is this method bad? Bad in terms of what?
Given that interoperability (compression, encryption) on other system is not a concern here.

More details:
I also somehow using the concept of pipelining.
For example:
i) [Sequential] Compress and then encrypt a file will take 10 + 20 = 30 seconds,
ii) [Pipelining] Compress the first half of the file, immediately start encryption after compression is done. At the same time, start compressing the second half of the file, and finally encrypt the second half after the compression is done. It might only take 20 seconds.
(I know it is a bad example, but just to give the idea of applying storage techniques into pipeline)
I am not sure about this, but since each chunk of a file does not depends on the previous chunk (no data dependencies problem), pipelining a file should be ok right?

Comment: 'it will not improve the I/O speed due to the limitation on single spinning hard disk'.  There are a lot of SO questions about multiple threads and one disk.  Nearly all the answers, including the accepted ones, make this claim.  Not one has any numbers to prove it.  It makes sort of intuitive sense, but with modern, intelligent controllers with large caches, and with sensibly large app buffers, who knows until they have tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it will actually speed up your program or not depends on a lot of factors.  This includes-  is the file in RAM or on disk?  If its on disk is the program IO bound or CPU bound (if IO bound then it won't help)?  How is the scheduler of the OS actually going to assign the threads-  is it going to assign them to the same core or multiple cores?  Do the different threads ever need to interact (will they be waiting locked for so long that its not a speedup or is very buggy)?

Your technique is a fairly standard one for parallel processing.  Whether its good for your app or not requires pretty much implementing and checking.

Comment: 1) File is initially in disk, read each chunk into bytebuffer and then process it. Is it in RAM now?  
2) I am not sure. Probably more CPU bound? (compression and encryption) But it also needs to read/write fast after processing (IO bound?).
3) I am also not sure. I mainly use Runnables or AsyncTask and thread pools. So it is not TRUE parallel programming here...
4) I think no. After each thread is complete, it just write the result into a new file (each thread write into different location using Java NIO).

about your last sentence, do you mean it is ok to do so?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, its perfectly ok to do so.  Like you mentioned yourself, its just like pipelining, which is the basic idea that all processors use to execute instructions in parallel.

Comment: Yeah - you just gotta try such things.  Making buffer sizes and thread pool counts configurable, (or, even better, tweakable at runtime), can help.  Also 'Runnables or AsyncTask and thread pools. So it is not TRUE parallel programming here' - sounds parallel to me:)